# how to: codedom ignoring warnings in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, compilation, warnings, codedom

im trying to build an application with using Code-Dom, the problem is that the compiler treats warnings as errors, i tried to specify it's parameters but with no luck

```
Dim Parameters As New CompilerParameters()
Parameters.WarningLevel = 0
Parameters.TreatWarningsAsErrors = False
```

the compiler works when there is no warnings, but i have no idea what to do?!
anything could be done?

here is one of the errors,
this one about

```
Thread.CurrentThread.Sleep(5000)
```

code:

```
Dim text123 As String = ""
        While True
            Thread.CurrentThread.Sleep(5000)
Dim s = go()
            If s <> text123 Then
                text123 = s
                functiontext("#" , s)
            End If
        End While
```

and the other errors about functions that don't return values

Comment: Can you show the code where you are handling the errors?

Comment: i added them to the main question

Comment: What is the warning for the `Sleep` line that causes the compile to fail?  What I meant with my first comment is, can you show more of the code where you are utilizing CodeDom.  Specifically I was interested in the area of the code where you handled the errors returned by the CodeDom compile method.

Comment: Access of shared member, constant member, enum member or nested type through an instance; qualifying expression will not be evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

**Are you sure it is not working?**

objCompileResults.Errors.HasErrors will return true even if there are just warnings.

**Is objCompileResults.CompiledAssembly = null?**

Here is some code I used to print out compile results with errors and warnings:

```cs
 CompilerResults objCompileResults = objCodeCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromFile( objCompilerParameters, files.ToArray() );

 // Check for compiler errors.
 // TODO: order by erros first (rather than warnings)
 if ( objCompileResults.Errors.HasErrors )
 {
    string errortext = "";
    string warningtext = "";
    foreach ( CompilerError mistake in objCompileResults.Errors )
    {
       if ( mistake.IsWarning == false )
       {
          string errorString = string.Format( "{0} Line: {1} Error: {2}", mistake.FileName, mistake.Line, mistake.ErrorText );
          errortext = errortext + errorString + Environment.NewLine;
       }
       else
       {
          string warningString = string.Format( "{0} Line: {1} Warning: {2}", mistake.FileName, mistake.Line, mistake.ErrorText );
          warningtext = warningtext + warningString + Environment.NewLine;
       }
    }
```

Comment: Right, that's why I was curious to see that part of the OP's code.  Good answer.  It's hard to say if this is the solution, but it probably is.